# Laravel Collections except not working as expected

Tags: laravel, collections

I create a collection for list of all address of a particular user and call it as:

```
$addresses = collect($user->GetAddress);
$addresses = $addresses->where('deleted', 0);
$addresses = $addresses->except(['deleted', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
```

I get the output like:

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "name": "mr.test",
            "line1": "test1",
            "line2": "test2",
            "pincode": 100,
            "city": "test3",
            "state": "test4",
            "mobile": "test5",
            "default": 0,
            "deleted": 0,
            "created_at": "2017-02-23 09:20:09",
            "updated_at": "2017-02-23 09:20:09"
        }
]
```

It still returns the fields that I do an except on. What am I doing wrong?

I even tried these:

```
$addresses = $addresses->each(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->except(['deleted', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
});
```

and

```
$addresses = $addresses->each->except(['deleted', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your possible solutions?

Comment: @Jerodev when I do `$addresses = $addresses->each->except(['deleted', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);` I get something like `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2508:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::except()`

Comment: Take a look at the solution I posted, this should help with this problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`except` only works when you have a single array with keys, not for a nested array. Your solution with the each function should work, but I think you have to cast `$item` to a collection first.

Like so:

```
$addresses = $addresses->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return collect($item)->except(['deleted', 'created_at', 'updated_at'])->toArray();
});
```

Comment: With this solution also, I still cant get rid of the fields, I tried `forget` as well as `except`, `only`.

Answer (score 4):

The `except` method works on the outer array/collection i.e. on the keys of the collection. So you'd have to use an `each` operator

The code below does not work because the `$item` is not a collection, but a model.

```
$addresses = $addresses->each(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->except(['deleted', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
});
```

### Solution 1

One solution to your problem would be to use the `select` method like this (provided GetAddresses is a real laravel [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)).

`$user->GetAddresses()->select(['col1', 'col2'])->get()`

### Solution 2

Another would be to map your output like so:

```
$addresses = $addresses->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return [
        "id": $item->id,
        "user_id": $item->user_id,
        "name": $item->name,
        "line1": $item->line1,
        // etc...
    ];
});
```

### Solution 3

Yet another solution would be to utilize the `$hidden` attribute (see [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)) on the model and use to to `toArray()` on each item. That would hide the attributes you have entered in the `$hidden` instance variable